# Hibernate join annotation on dynamic value

Tags: hibernate

I am stuck with poorly designed database schema and I need to join a table based on composite key, where one field is missing (having such FK is OK in MySql, but Hibernate complains about it).

```
@ManyToOne  
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column=@JoinColumn(name = "par_mascode", referencedColumnName = "mascode", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="dynamicVariable", referencedColumnName = "maslang")) })
public Master getMaster() {
    return this.master;
}
```

`dynamicVariable` should represent current user's selected Locale, which is obtained in code (not present in DB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `@Formula` supports only standard SQL, I came up with workaround using database session variable.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)   
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column=@JoinColumn(name = "par_mascode", referencedColumnName = "mascode", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="@lang", referencedColumnName = "maslang")) })
public Master getMaster() {
    return this.master;
}

//called before getting list of entities
Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SET @lang=:lang").setParameter("lang", Utils.getLanguageIdFromContext());
nativeQuery.executeUpdate();
```